# Is there an easier keyboard shortcut for taking a screenshot on OSX 10.5?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I'm running OSX 10.5 and was wondering if there is an easier way to make screenshots *which save to clipboard?*

I know I can use:

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

However this is hard on the fingers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set up a custom shortcut, for example a key, for that purpose.

Open System Prefrences, go to Keyboard -> Screen Shots (or navigate to the Screen Shot-options), and double click on the shortcuts you want to change to change them to the keys you use less frequently. If you have a huge keyboard like me, you can for example set the <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> to be the shortcuts.

Here is a screen shot of the settings window where you set the shortcut (captured with those as well!) The "Copy"-screenshots are the ones with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
[image: Screenshot]